# Cgo linker errors on C constants

Tags: c, linker, go, ld, cgo

I'm using cgo to wrap a C library and have run into a strange set of linker errors. I've boiled the problem down to the following:

A file header.h contains

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#define CONSTANT1 ("")
#define CONSTANT2 ""
#define CONSTANT3 ((char*)0)
#define CONSTANT4 (char*)0

#endif /* HEADER_H */
```

And test.go contains

```
package main

/*
#include "header.h"
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    _ = C.CONSTANT1
    _ = C.CONSTANT2
    _ = C.CONSTANT3
    _ = C.CONSTANT4
}
```

Upon running `go run test.go` I get the following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
... _cgo_main.o:(.data.rel+0x0): undefined reference to `CONSTANT4'
... _cgo_main.o:(.data.rel+0x8): undefined reference to `CONSTANT3'
... _cgo_main.o:(.data.rel+0x10): undefined reference to `CONSTANT1'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have two questions about this:

1. Why does the linker have anything to do with pre-defined constants?
2. Why do `CONSTANT1`, `CONSTANT3`, `CONSTANT4` show up as undefined, but not `CONSTANT2`?

Thanks in advance.

*Edit: Constants defined as other values (e.g. ints) work fine.

*Edit2: Using go version go1.1.2 linux/amd64

*Edit3: A complete example of failure:

I'm working with the C OpenLDAP library and would like to use the `LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE` constant. It's defined in `ldap.h` as

```
#define LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE    ((char*)0)
#define LDAP_SASL_NULL      ("")
```

The `LDAP_SASL_NULL` constant gives the same error.

A minimal demonstrative go program:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lldap

#include <ldap.h>
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    _ = C.LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE
}
```

Comment: Wild guess; if it is correct: Go wants to access the data through the ABI (proper linkage), using a symbol name. And that's not what preprocessor macros do. (I may be wrong since I've never used Go.)

Comment: @FUZxxl (Now guess who solved several Java, Python and Lua "problems" without knowing any of those languages... :P)

Comment: Hm... I guess that's because the other constants are encapsulated in braces or contain casts which may confuse cgo. It would be nice if you could show a minimal complete example that exhibits your problem. Best if you could link to the actual library.

Comment: For the record: My deleted comment (originally the second one) read: @H2CO3 You're right. I deleted it because I was confused by OP's question and questioned myself.

Comment: You said that one of the constants worked even though another did not. Which one did work? For the example you provided, my original example applies. You need to redefine the constant in your Go code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did originally answer something different based on how I thought cgo works. But if `CONSTANT2` is recognized by cgo, something different might be the reason. Could you please:

- run the tool `nm` on the library file and tell whether the output contains `CONSTANT2` or any other constants you refer to that were at the same time established through `#define`. A library might declare a `#define` constant at the same time as a global symbol to get around compatibility issues.
- provide a minimal working example of your problem if possible. This is, an example that can be compiled by someone who reads your post and exhibits your problem. Your question looks like it may miss some important parts to answer it. For instance, it would be nice to know the actual library you have problems with.

---

### original answer

If you use `#define`, you do not establish anything the compiler will actually see. A `#define` is a preprocessing directive that is removed before parsing. To establish constants the compiler (and thus cgo) can see, actually declare them:

```
const char *CONSTANT1 = "";
const char *CONSTANT2 = "";
const char *CONSTANT3 = (char*)0;
const char *CONSTANT4 = (char*)0;
```

If you cannot touch the header, there is typically not much  you can do; you basically have to duplicate all constants in the Go part of your code:

```
const (
     CONSTANT1 = "",
     CONSTANT2 = "",
     CONSTANT3 = nil,
     CONSTANT4 = nil,
 )
```

You could try complex tricks like running cpp over your Go code, but this is likely to cause more trouble than it would solve problems.